# Java: Calling a method in a raw Class which's name is undefined?

Tags: java, class, parameters

Right, first I have no idea what this would be called so I hope the title is correct?

In my main class `Main.java` it'll run this piece of code:

```
ClassTwo cTwo new ClassTwo();

cTwo.addEvent(new EventOne());
cTwo.addEvent(new EventTwo());
cTwo.addEvent(new EventThree());
```

Now within ClassTwo's addEvent() I have it as:

```
public void addEvent(Class<?> event) {
    event.update();
}
```

The `Class<?> event` was just put there as I have no idea where else to start at. The `event.update()` of course comes with an error as there is no such method in type `Class`. Every event class will have an `update()` method in them so how would I go about making this work?

Edit:
Ok my question wasn't really clear.
Everything in ClassTwo will be made into an API and contains it also a gameloop thread. Interfaces I have no idea about but `java.lang.reflect.Method` looks like something that would do want I'm looking for.

Edit2:
This is the update method:

```
private BufferedImage gameImage;

public void update() {
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gameImage.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, gSystem.getWidth() - 1, gSystem.getHeight() - 1);
    ///////////
    // Change to the image made here will differ for each event.
    ///////////
    cTwo.setGameImage(gameImage);
}
```

Comment: Assuming `Class` is `java.lang.Class`, it doesn't have an `update` method. It's unclear what you expect this to do or why. Are you supposed to pass the `Class` object for some type of `Event` subtype? What are you then supposed to do with that? Instantiate it and invoke its `update` method? Is it a `static` method? Is it an instance method? Do all of these subtypes have a single parameterless constructor? How do you plan to instantiate them?

Comment: Read the full description please, I already stated that. It is not static

Comment: Have you heard about [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)?

Comment: Isn't this just basic OOP? `Class<?>` need to be a base event class or interface type that has an `update()` method? If not, the the question isn't clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to have `EventOne`, `EventTwo` and `EventThree` all extend the same `Interface` (let's call it `Event`).

This `Event` interface has one unimplemented method called `update`.

Then your addEvent method will look like this:

```
public void addEvent(Event event) {
    event.update();
}
```

Comment: Would the code within `update()` be changeable for each event class?

Comment: Yes, since each Class will have it's own implementation of update(). I would suggest googling "Interfaces Java". I believe this will help to give you a better understand of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've never used interfaces before, now I feel stupid. T~T

Comment: @sevnnndiscet - Not to worry. People on this site tend to forget that once they were complete newbies also. We all started at the bottom! Good luck!